# TFS Test Suite automation execution order

Tags: tfs, automated-tests

Currently I am using TFS vNext Run Functional Tests (RFT) using ​Test Plan.  I would like to be able to run specific tests first in a specified order before running other tests.  I thought that I could maybe do this by using a parent-suite that had tests that I wanted to run first, and then have a child-suite under that parent that would run all other tests.  I am not sure if TFS executes suites in any particular order.  I haven't found much documentation stating if parent-suites execute before their child-suites execute.  Is this a safe assumption on my part or is there some other way to execute tests in a specific order using RFT?

Comment: Tests that depend on other tests are evil.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For VSTS and TFS 2017 and later versions, you can order the test suites as per your needs. Prior to this capability, the suites were only ordered alphabetically. Now, using the drag-and-drop capability in Test hub, suites can be reordered among the peer suites or moved to another suite in the hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: So, it sounds like since I am using TFS 2015, this will not work for me.  Do I need to name the Suites so the order works the way I want using alphabetizing?  Will this make the execution order to follow the same rule?

Comment: Sorry that I don't have TFS 2015 to test this, but in TFS 2017 (use VS test task), test suites will order as the TEST tab shows when you select them. You may have a test on your side.